# RDLC get ObjectDataSourceSelectMethod programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

I have an embedded RDLC report in my application.

I am using `localReport.GetDataSourceNames()` to get the datasources listed in the RDLC, but I also need to know the `ObjectDataSourceSelectMethod` of the datasource.

Is there any way to get it programmatically?

**UPDATE** - some more details

The project is a WPF project, my RDLC's are all in a "Web Projct" as to make use of Object Data Sources, I then reference that assembly and load my embedded reports into a Stream:

```
     Assembly.Load("FleetManagement.Resources")
                .GetManifestResourceStream(string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                            "FleetManagement.Resources.Reports.",
                                            "FleetList.rdlc"));
```

I then get the datasourcename using the following method:

```
    private string DataSourceName 
    { 
        get
        {
            var ass = Assembly.Load("FleetManagement.Resources");
            var rpt = new LocalReport();

            using (var stream = ass.GetManifestResourceStream(string.Format("{0}{1}", "FleetManagement.Resources.Reports.", "FleetList.rdlc")))
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    using (TextReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        rpt.LoadReportDefinition(rdr);
                        return rpt.GetDataSourceNames().FirstOrDefault();
                    }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now want I want to do is get the `ObjectDataSourceSelectMethod` from that report similar to how I get the `DataSetName`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `ObjectDataSource` I suppose your application is in **ASP.NET**.

You can get `DataSourceId` using the name obtained by `.GetDataSourceNames`:

```
Dim strDataSourceId as String = YourReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources("NameObtainedByGetDataSourceNames").DataSourceId
```

In ASP.NET you can use it to find the corrispective `ObjectDataSource` in your `Page`; note that you use a `Master` page you need two `FindControl`:

```
Dim strSelectMethod as String = CType(CType(Me.Master.FindControl("cphPage"), ContentPlaceHolder).FindControl(strDataSourceId), ObjectDataSource).SelectMethod
```

Comment: please see my updated question, I am not using asp.net

Comment: wow! this is a completely different problem. do you know the structure of the web project? are ObjectDataSources embedded in a aspx Page?

Answer (score -1):

when you define the report if you do this;

```
<rs:ReportViewer ID="TestrptViewer" runat="server"...>
<LocalReport ReportPath="myreport.rdlc">
    <DataSources>
        <rs:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="FleetsReport" />
    </DataSources>
</LocalReport>
</rs:ReportViewer>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetFleets" TypeName="DatasetType">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Then I suppose you can extract ReportDataSource which is a ObjectDataSource type and then get SelectMethod. I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: I am NOT using asp.net